# keep container div from shifting last content div to the next line on zoom out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this mothly calander with day blocks 1- (28-31) blocks per month depending on the month. there are 6 'option' blocks at the beginning which are shown or hidden depending on what day of the week the month starts, so if the month starts on a Monday, all the blocks are hidden and if its Sunday, all these blocks are shown. The problem is when the page is zoomed out to 75% or less the 'sunday' block shifts down a line. If you see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NX2vM/) and zoom out to 75% you will see what I mean. here is my CSS. Thanks.

```
.container{ width:58ex; 
            border:1px solid black;
            position:absolute;
          }

.date{  width:8ex; 
        height:8ex;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        float:left;
       }

  .day{ width:8ex;
        height:4ex;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        float:left; 
        background-color:grey;
       }

.option{ width:8ex;
        height:8ex;
        border: 1px solid white;
        float:left;
      }
```

Comment: maybe CSS styles `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell` would be a better fit? This is a table, why not style it as such?

Comment: there are no rows (only cells)...

Comment: I had used table-cell on a previous version, but the results weren't great. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The problem is your days' width property (in `ex`), when combined with the border property (in `px`), extends beyond the container `<div>` width, which forces the floated elements onto the next line. Still trying to think up an elegant solution...

Comment: much appreciated, Set Sail Media.

Comment: I think I've got it, although it will require some additional HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by making these changes in CSS:

```
.container {
     width:56ex;   // <-- instead of 58ex
     ...

.container > * { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

See, also, this [**short demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2YYx4/) (based on the code you provided).

**IMPORTANT**:
As  [Set Sail Media](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999553/set-sail-media) kindly reminded me, this technic is **not** support in IE version 7 and older. See **[here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)** for more details.

**Short explanation**:
*Cause of the problem*:
`.container` div's width is "58ex". Each `.day` div's width is "8ex" and its border is "1px" on each side; a total of "8ex + 2px". We have to fit 7 `.day` divs inside `.container`'s 58ex's, that is:

```
7 * (8ex + 2px) = 56ex + 14px must fit in 58ex <=>
14px must fit in 2ex
```

Since 'px' is a static unit, but 'ex' changes dynamically (based on the font's size, which in turn depends on the zooming factor). Inevitably, we come at a point where `14px > 1ex`, so the last div does not fit on the line and has to be folded on a new line.

*'border-box' to the resque*:
Quoting MDN, what you achive using `box-sizing:border-box` is that:
"The width and height properties include the padding **and** border, but not the margin." (emphasis mine)
So, you basically tell the browser, you want the `.day` divs to be 8ex wide **including** content, padding **and** border. You can read more about it **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**.

Comment: Good solution if your user base is not using <= IE7 http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: Ooops ! You are right ! I don't have to support IE, so I often forget other people do :P Thx for the reminder.

Comment: Thankfully, that percentage of users keeps dropping and dropping :}P

Comment: fantastic solution, thanks. I'm not too worried about old IE versions at the moment. That might be something to explore later. But for now this solution is just what I need, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the trick here was to use additional HTML markup to style the children and parent `<div>`s separately. You can play around with the dimensions as you need, but this should hold true if you do the math correct (each `.day` and `.date` `width` property needs to be 1/7th of `.container`'s `width`).

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NX2vM/10/

How does this work? The parent `<div>` (`.day` and `.date`) contain the width property. We add a child, whose height we set and whose width will adapt automatically to the parent. We apply the border to this child div, so the border is "inset" (100px wide including the border) vs. outset (100px + 1px left border + 1px right border = 102px )

HTML (note the duplicate divs):

```
<div class = "container">

<div class = "day"><div>mon</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>tue</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>wed</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>thu</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>fri</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>sat</div></div>
<div class = "day"><div>sun</div></div>


<div class = "option" id = "opp_1"></div>
<div class = "option" id = "opp_2"></div>
<div class = "option" id = "opp_3"></div>
<div class = "option" id = "opp_4"></div>
<div class = "option" id = "opp_5"></div>
<div class = "option" id = "opp_6"></div>

<div class = "date"><div>1</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>2</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>3</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>4</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>5</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>6</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>7</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>8</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>9</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>10</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>11</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>12</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>13</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>14</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>15</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>16</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>17</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>18</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>19</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>20</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>21</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>22</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>23</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>24</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>25</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>26</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>27</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>28</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>29</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>30</div></div>
<div class = "date"><div>31</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 700px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
}

.date{ 
    width:100px; 
    float:left;
}
.date div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height:50px;
}

.day{ 
    width:100px;
    float:left; 
    background-color:grey;
}
.day div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height:20px;
}

.option{ 
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: another great solution. for my current version, I think I will use the box- sizing method, but I am keeping this code as an option for later, so Thank you very much for the answer, if I could except both answers I would. +1, anyway.